# How to find duplicate jars with different versions

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Let's say I have a list of jars like this.

```
a_1.0.0.jar
b_1.0.0.jar
b_2.0.0.jar
c_1.0.0.jar
c_1.3.0.jar
c_3.2.0.jar
d_2.0.0.jar
e_3.0.0.jar
```

I want to get the duplicated jar list.

Like this

```
b_1.0.0.jar
b_2.0.0.jar
c_1.0.0.jar
c_1.3.0.jar
c_3.2.0.jar
```

or Like this

```
b
c
```

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the filenames are all built up like that, you can do something like this:

```
ls | sed 's/_.*//' | uniq --repeated
```

This lists all files, strips the underscore and everything after that, and then uses `uniq` to only print the repeated lines.

Answer (score 1):

To get the second output:

```
<list.txt sort -u | cut -d _ -f 1 | uniq -d
```

The procedure:

1. `sort` sorts, so `uniq` can do its job later. With `-u` the tool collapses identical lines, so they won't generate a false positive. (Your example doesn't contain duplicates; this is a general precaution).
2. `cut` takes `_` as separator and prints the first field, so only `a`, `b`, etc. survive.
3. `uniq -d` only prints repeated lines, once for each group.

Notes:

- Extra `_` in any name will break the above logic.
- Your example is sorted and without duplicates. If the actual data is like this, you won't need `sort`.